# Does Telegram API support swipes?

Tags: api, telegram

If I have a bunch of pictures, Is there any way to see all the pictures like on the Right Image, instead of the standard way (Left Image)

[image]

Comment: Data API are generally UI agnostic - they don't care how you plan to present the data you requested. They just provide the data you requested, in the format they were told to provide. If you choose to display all results on the same page at once, that is not an API concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the responsibility of Telegram API to support swipes.  This will be down to the UI library you are using to build your app.  All native apps should support swipes by default, however, by the looks of your UI widget you are trying to implement a Carousel as there are forward and back icons.  If you let us know what platform you are targeting, what language / framework you are using there should be loads of useful suggestions.

Comment: I'm using a python library called pyTelegramBotAPI to make a Telegram Bot

Comment: But what platform are you targeting?  Android / iOS / web etc.  Are you using a JavaScript or UI framework?

Comment: Uhm, I'm confused, it would be just a chatbot inside Telegram App. And no, I'm not using anything except Python and pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: If it is just a bot then why do you need a swipe left function?  Your "app" has to target a platform, the platform that you are targeting will dictate how you implement UI functionality.  Python / Telegram API are not a factor here.